# Click Event using Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: javascript, php, ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to fire a click event using Capybara and Poltergeist.

My object is:

```
<div id="sticker-reserva">
    <button type="button" id="reservebtn" onclick="makeReservation()" class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block m-b-2 disabled">Reservar</a>
</div>
```

My implemented steps:

```
When(/^user makes a reservation (.*)-(.*)$/) do |block,room|
    visit $baseUrl+'/calendar/day/02/01/2016'
    find(:xpath,'//div[@data="'+block+'/'+room+'"]').click

    expect(page).to have_xpath("//div[@data='"+block+"/"+room+"' and @class='col-xs-2 calendario-diario-celda  press']")
    page.execute_script("$('#reservebtn').click()")
    step "I fill the form data"
    page.execute_script('$("#saveReservation").click()')
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'modal-body')]/p[2]", :text=>'Se ha guardado correctamente la reservación.')
    find(:xpath,"//div[contains(@class,'modal-footer')]/button[@class='btn btn-border btn-default']").click
end
```

When I tested using Selenium instead of Poltergeist, everything works without problem.

The error is generated with: `page.execute_script("$('#reservebtn').click()")`

I used page.expect assertions to verify that the button was not being clicked.

I've tried changing the line mentioned with this options:

```
find(:xpath,'//button[@id="reservebtn"]').click
click_button 'reservebtn'
find(:xpath,'//div[@id="sticker-reserva"]').click
page.execute_script('makeReservation()');
page.execute_script("$('#reservebtn').click()")
```

UPDATE

1) The execution of the scenario throws this output:

```
Scenario: Reservation                       # features/reservation.feature:13
    Given I am logged in as <USER_ROLE_SALES> # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:39
    When user makes a reservation 1-C         # features/step_definitions/reservation_steps.rb:33
      expected to find xpath "//div[@id=\"central-zone\"]/h1[@class=\"page-header\"]" with text "Nueva Reserva" but there were no matches. Also found "Calendario Diario Descargar Reporte", which matched the selector but not all filters. (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/reservation_steps.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/reservation_steps.rb:45:in `/^user makes a reservation (.*)-(.*)$/'
      features/reservation.feature:15:in `When user makes a reservation 1-C'
    Then the reservation in 1-C is logged     # features/step_definitions/reservation_steps.rb:66
```

"Calendario Diario Descargar Reporte" is the title for the original page where the reservation button is.

2) Clicking on the 'reservebtn' should change the page and show the Reservation form, the page Title is "Nueva Reserva". But what is happening now is that the system stays in the view that has the button.

3) makeReservation() grabs information from the current view and calls a method in php that shows the reservation form and fills some data like the date selected and the room selected for the event.

```
makeReservation(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        $('#reservebtn').prop('disabled',true);
        var reservationInfo = [];
        $(".press").each(function (index) {
            reservationInfo.push($(this).attr("data"));
            console.log(index + ": " + $(this).attr("data"));
        });

        console.log(reservationInfo);

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('reservation') }}',
            data: {reservationInfo: reservationInfo, date: $('#dateNow').val()},
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#modalLoading').modal('show');
            }
        }).done(function (a) {
            removeModal();
            $('.main').html(a);
        }).error(function (a) {
            removeModal();
            modalDefault('', 'Ha ocurrido un error. Vuelva a intentarlo', '', '', [0, 0, 1],[0], 'Entendido', 'error.svg');
        });
    }
}
```

4) The versions I am using are: PhantomJs 2.1.1.0 and Poltergeist 1.10.0
5) This is the config file for my tests:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/mechanize'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'test/unit/assertions'
require 'mechanize'
require_relative 'browser_config'

World(Test::Unit::Assertions)

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    options = {
        :js_errors => false,
        :inspector => true,
        :debug => false
    }
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost"
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app = "make sure this isn't nil"
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5

World(Capybara)
```

Comment: It doesn't excute the steps in "I fill the form data" because it doesn't find the inputs that the script has to fill. I added an expect assertion to verify that after the click event on "reservebtn" it shows the form, and it always fails on it.

Comment: @AnaPardo Edit your question and add the complete exact error message you get.  Also what EXACTLY is clicking on the "reservebtn" button supposed to do - does it open a modal? does it change the page?, etc, etc (showing the definition of makeReservation() would help there).  Also do you have `js_errors` turned on in your poltergeist config, and what version of Poltergeist and PhantomJS are you using?